# How to load 4 unsigned chars and convert them to signed shorts with NEON?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, simd, neon

I want to load 4 unsigned chars (8 bit) from the memory and widen them to signed shorts (16 bit). How can I do that with NEON intrinsics?

From the list of NEON intrinsics, I can see only load options for 8 unsigned chars at a time. But I want to do for 4 unsigned chars. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you tell me in the form of intrinisics. I don't want to use assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it will be look similar to this:

```
inline int16x4_t LoadAndConvert4(const uint8_t * p)
{
    return vreinterpret_s16_u16(vget_low_u16(vmovl_u8(
        vreinterpret_u8_u32(vdup_n_u32(*(uint32_t*)p)))));
}
```

Or step by step:

```
inline int16x4_t LoadAndConvert4(const uint8_t * p)
{
    uint32_t u32 = *(uint32_t*)p;
    uint32x2_t u32x2 = vdup_n_u32(a32);
    uint8x8_t u8x8 = vreinterpret_u8_u32(a32x2);
    uint16x8_t u16x8 = vmovl_u8(a8x8);
    uint16x4_t u16x4 = vget_low_u16(a16x8);
    return vreinterpret_s16_u16(u16x4);
}
```

Comment: I ge the following error, file.c:1239: error: request for member 'val' in 'vmovl_u8(((__builtin_neon_uqi __vector__)vdup_n_u32((*(uint32_t*)ucptr))))', which is of non-class type '__builtin_neon_uhi __vector__'
file.c:1240: error: cannot convert '__builtin_neon_hi __vector__' to 'const int16_t*' for argument '1' to '__builtin_neon_hi __vector__ vld1_s16(const int16_t*)'

Comment: @pythonic I'm sorry. I forgot one closing parenthesis.

Comment: Still get error: cannot convert '__builtin_neon_uhi __vector__' to '__builtin_neon_uhi __vector__' in initialization. Also, I want a vector of signed shorts, not unsigned shorts.

Comment: As we converted unsigned 8-byte integers to unsigned 16-byte (0xFF -> 0x00FF) so we can cast theirs to signed 16-byte integers.